# Django, noReverseMatch

Tags: django

Hello I am struggling making cart to my e-commerce web app. I get error NoReverseMatch because of:

```
<a class= "navbar__link" href="{% url 'cart-page' item.id %}">Cart</a>
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, item_id, *args, **kwargs):
    item = Item.objects.get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)
    order_item= OrderItem.objects.get_object_or_create( order_item = item, quantity=1)
    order = Order.objects.get_object_or_create(order_user=request.user, order_items=order_item)
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Cart updated!")
    return redirect('cart-page')
```

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=11)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = MoneyField(
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0,
        default_currency='USD',
        max_digits=11,
    )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='static/images/man.png')
    description = models.TextField(default="Item")
```

*EDIT*

My urls as you wanted.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', ShopDetailView.as_view(), name='detail-page'),
    path('cart', views.add_to_cart, name='cart-page')
]
```

Any advices?

Comment: what is the url you have entered and post your `urls.py`

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: `cart-page` doesn't take a card id, `detail-page` does however

Comment: Your second path doesn't have the parameter. It should be in this way: `path('cart/<int:id>', views.add_to_cart, name='cart-page')`

Comment: Either did not work,  'cart/<int:id>', 'cart/<int:pk>'.